# How to find maximum occurences of element x in a unsorted array such that (x>=Y || x<=Z) in a subarry with minimum number of probes?

Tags: c++, arrays, search

SO, I am trying to search for an element x which is either >=max or <=min, min and max are two varibles. I want as many such x as possible within search space. I limit my searh attempts to some number say 512. Now, out of those 512 attempts only a few will be successful. Basically, if I start searching from i then I'll go till i+512 only. So, is it possible to reduce the attempts by increment i with more than 1 after some number of unsucessful probes. Moreover, it's two comparasion for each element I check. Can I reduce it.

Comment: In an unsorted array you will have to check every number, if I understand you correctly. Every number you ignore could be the one you were looking for.

Comment: Just do a linear traversal.  That's basically the fastest thing you can do on a modern machine.

Comment: I was doing this on random numbres and I could see there were long runs when I didn't found the element I was looking for based on that I was thinking if I could do anything.